# Solr Error instantiating class:'org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.TruncateTokenFilterFactory'

Tags: java, solr, lucene, wikipedia

I am doing indexing wikipedia dumps to solr-6.6.0. While there is some error like this
Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at least one immense term in field="text" (whose UTF8 encoding is longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the first immense term is: '[10, 10, 70, 111, 117, 110, 100, 32, 116, 104, 105, 115, 32, 111, 110, 32, 116, 104, 101, 32, 119, 101, 98, 32, 104, 111, 112, 101, 32, 116]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 43225
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:671)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:300)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:234)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:450)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1475)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc0(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:239)
    at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.addDoc(DirectUpdateHandler2.java:163)
    ... 54 more
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash$MaxBytesLengthExceededException: bytes can be at most 32766 in length; got 43225
    at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:284)
```

So I modified the schema in core and added this line.

```
<filter class="solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory" prefixLength="32700"/>
```

But when I restart the solr server, it always gave the error notification:
    Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] analyzer/filter: Error instantiating class: 'org.apache.lucene.analysis.miscellaneous.TruncateTokenFilterFactory'

Did I set the value 32700 wrong? What is the maximum length?
Here is my schema file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema version="1.5" name="wikipedia">

    <fieldType name="text_wiki" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WikipediaTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
            <filter class="indexer.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/> -->
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="2" max="32700" />
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                    ignoreCase="true"
                    words="lang/stopwords_en.txt"
                    />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPossessiveFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.KeywordMarkerFilterFactory" protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <!-- Optionally you may want to use this less aggressive stemmer instead of PorterStemFilterFactory:
            <filter class="indexer.EnglishMinimalStemFilterFactory"/> -->
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="int" class="solr.TrieIntField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="double" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="0" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
    <field name="_version_" type="long" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
    <field name="TITLE" type="text_wiki" indexed="true" stored="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />
    <field name="REVISION_TEXT" type="text_wiki" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" termVectors="true" termPositions="true" termOffsets="true" />
    <field name="REVISION_TIMESTAMP" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="CONTRIBUTOR_ID" type="int" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
    <field name="CONTRIBUTOR_USERNAME" type="string" indexed="true" docValues="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />

    <dynamicField name="*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</schema>
```

Comment: I read the https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/update/processor/TruncateFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.java And it says <code>StrField</code> will be truncated to no more then 100 characters. So does it mean the maximum length should be just 100

Comment: Try "solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory". Are you sure you want a field with tokens 32,700 characters in length, though? That doesn't sound like a very useful field for searching...

Comment: @femtoRgon I set the Wikipedia revision text_wiki type. I tried solr.TruncateTokenFilterFactory prefixLength=32,700, it doesn't work.  instantiating error. How much I should set? Now I am trying filter the length directly which are more than 32700

Comment: Basically, what this error means is that your field is not being tokenized. I think you need to figure out why it isn't being tokenized. Seeing your fieldType defintion would be helpful there. You could make it index the field without errors by truncating, but you'll have trouble when you attempt to search that field.

Comment: Hi, I add my schema file in the question now